# Using the Umbraco v7.2.1 Grid Layout in a Webforms project

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, umbraco, grid-layout

I have a website built using Umbraco v7.2.1 (recently upgraded from 6) and I am trying to use the new "Simple editor" which uses the bootstrap grid layout to allow users to dynamically add columns and rows.

I have setup a new document type and masterpage (currently rendering in Webforms mode) that is essentially blank, I always create a basic master template then one for the home page and one for the "further" pages both of which inherit from the master (see below for example of master -> home)

**Master page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title><umbraco:Item field="pageTitle" runat="server" /></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Home page master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/PropertyProfessionalsMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">

<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">

    @Model.Content.GetGridHtml("bodyContent")

</umbraco:Macro>

</asp:Content>
```

I have tried a few things including creating a Partial View that has the following line:

```
@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("propertyAlias")
```

And also using an Inline Razor Macro as I am currently doing in the above master page, the Partial View would not load under any circumstances even when I just put the words "Hello World" in it (literally nothing else), it gave me an "error loading partial view script".

I gave up on Partial Views thinking that they would simply not play nicely with Webforms mode and resorted to using Razor (please let me know if this was a mistake).

Using the above code it renders nothing, it doesn't error which is a start and if I swap it to use the @CurrentPage it does error so it must be doing something, I just can't figure out what.

I would like to take advantage of the new grid layout editors because they look awesome but converting my entire website to MVC is not an option at this time (it is a big website and would take months to rebuild all the controls).

Does anybody have any working examples of a basic masterpage that renders the JSON data from the grid layout?

Comment: can you post your master page and home after you switched to razor?

Comment: The example posted above is using the inline Razor (cshtml) in the master page, I also tried creating a separate macro with the same razor line but that did the same thing and seemed to introduce an extra layer of complexity that I was trying to avoid for the purpose of the question (so people didn't get hung up on trying to figure out why the macro wasn't working), does that help or was there something else you needed to see?

Answer (score 0):

The `GetGridHtml()` method needs two arguments: the first is the string alias of the page field / property you want to render; the second is the rendering editor template you want to pass this model to.

For example:

```
@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("body", "Foundation1")
```

...where "body" is the field name of my page (you'd use "bodyContent") and "Foundation1" is the name of the grid template name that I've used, which sits under /Partials/Grid.

By default Umbraco creates two partial views here: Bootstrap2 and Bootstrap3 (no idea where #1 went). I like to use other CSS frameworks so have used Foundation in my example above.

Does this solve your issue?